# Passing auth header to permitAll path throws 401

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an API configured with Spring Security's permitAll():

```
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api").permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }

}
```

While this works, I noticed if you include an Authorization Basic header, Spring Security will still try to process and validate the auth header.

I'm using AWS API gateway for authorization. AWS will then forward the request to my application. The thing is, AWS API gateway forwards the auth header to the app.

What's the best way to solve this, do I remove the header before AWS sends the request to the app? or I configure Spring Security to disregard the auth header if an API is public?

Comment: Just to add, I added spring security because the application may be deployed with app-level security or API gateway auth + public app api.

Comment: try `http.httpBasic().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api").permitAll()`

Comment: @dgzz did you find an answer. I am facing this in 2022 :) Help is appreciated.